# Are doxygen non-graphical call and caller trees possible?

Tags: doxygen

I'm aware of the CALL_GRAPH and CALLER_GRAPH doxygen [configuration options](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/diagrams.html), which produce call and caller graphs, respectively.

I would like a non-graphical representation of this same information, but can't figure out how.  I've used this capability in the past so it must have existed at some point, and may still exist.

How can I get non-graphical call and caller trees?  Is this even possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The configuration options are: [REFERENCES_RELATION](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/config.html#cfg_references_relation) and [REFERENCED_BY_RELATION](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/config.html#cfg_referenced_by_relation).  And now I know.